# Guava ForwardingList usage example

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am looking for sample code which explains Guava ForwardingList class. Basically I am implementing a custom ArrayList class which will be used to solve this requirement mentioned in [my earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492786/sync-multiple-source-arraylists-into-single-target-list). I never used Google collection before. But by just looking at the [JavaDoc of ForwardingList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html), I think I can implement my custom class by sub classing ForwardingList.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`ForwardingList`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) (which [`extends ForwardingCollection`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingCollection.html), which in turn [`extends ForwardingObject`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingObject.html)) implements the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

To use, you simply need to do two things:

- `@Override delegate()` to return the backing delegate instance that methods are forwarded to
- `@Override` whatever `List` method you want/need to decorate

The decorator pattern allows you to use composition instead of inheritance (*Effective Java 2nd Edition, Favor composition over inheritance*), and `ForwardingList` from Guava provides a convenient template from which to write your own `List` implementation, providing all the plumbing mechanism for you.

Note that if you are planning to decorate an `ArrayList`, you'd probably want your `ForwardingList` subclass to also implement [`RandomAccess`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html).

---

#### Example: `ListWithDefault`

Here's an (incomplete!) example of a `ForwardingList` that substitutes `null` values in the delegate with a given default value.

```
import java.util.*;
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class ListWithDefault<E> extends ForwardingList<E> {
    final E defaultValue;
    final List<E> delegate;

    ListWithDefault(List<E> delegate, E defaultValue) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    @Override protected List delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }
    @Override public E get(int index) {
        E v = super.get(index);
        return (v == null ? defaultValue : v);
    }
    @Override public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        final Iterator<E> iter = super.iterator();
        return new ForwardingIterator<E>() {
            @Override protected Iterator<E> delegate() {
                return iter;
            }
            @Override public E next() {
                E v = super.next();
                return (v == null ? defaultValue : v); 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

We can then test it as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ListWithDefault<String>(
            Arrays.asList("Alice", null, "Bob", "Carol", null),
            "UNKNOWN"
        );

        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        // Alice
        // UNKNOWN
        // Bob
        // Carol
        // UNKNOWN

        System.out.println(names);
        // [Alice, null, Bob, Carol, null]
}
```

Note that this is an *incomplete* implementation. The `toString()` method still returns the delegate's `toString()`, which isn't aware of the default value. A few other methods must be `@Override` as well for a more complete implementation.

Comment: For a more complete example, see `private class ContrainedList` here: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Constraints.java

Answer (score 4):

You should implement [delegate()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html#delegate()) method of ForwardingList to return delegate list you are using in your elements.

```
public class YourList<E> extends ForwardingList<E> {
    private final List<E> delegate;

    public YourList(List<E> list1, List<E> list2) {
        delegate = new ArrayList<E>(list1);
        delegate.addAll(list2);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }
}
```