# Java: How to extend a base class when other classes already extend the base?

Tags: java, oop

I want to extend a base class in apache commons email, the base class is Email. I simply want to add some throttling to the .send() method

3 other classes extend Email: HtmlEmail, SimpleEmail, and MultiPartEmail

There is no factory method for creating these 3 derived classes.

Is there a best way that I can extend this one method from the base Email class? All I can think of is to extend the 3 derived classes, override .send() in each, and have each of them call a common static method to accomplish the .send() throttling functionality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and write e.g. a `ThrottledEmail`. It simply decorates another instance of `Email` (it can be *ANY* `Email` subclass) and it can `@Override` the `send` method to enforce some throttling. All other methods are simply delegated to the underlying `Email` instance.

This is similar to how a [`java.io.BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) works, for example. It can decorate any `Reader` to give it a buffering feature. Other examples include [`java.util.Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) that provides utility methods such as [`Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) which wraps *ANY* `Collection<T>` and decorates it with synchronization features.

Unless the base class is clearly documented to facilitate subclasses to `@Override` certain methods, you should generally favor composition (*has-a*) over inheritance (*is-a*) relationship.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance, or else prohibit it*

#### Related questions

- [when do we need Decorator Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477962/when-do-we-need-decorator-pattern)
- [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)
- [Examples of GoF Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)
- [Guava `ForwardingList` usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502066/guava-forwardinglist-usage-example)

Comment: This is great, I've read a number of tutorials on this pattern. But I don't quite grasp it fully:

If I need an HtmlEmail (it extends Email), and all I need is to add functionality to Email.send(), do I also need a ConcreteDecorator for HtmlEmail (and in turn for all other subclasses of Email - SimpleEmail & MultiPartEmail, implementing all respective methods to forward on to the concrete object)?

Comment: @David: You have concrete decorators for each decoration. So you may have a `ThrottledEmail` which throttles the send of any `Email`, and you may later have further decorations on other aspects of `Email` (e.g. `AutosignedEmail` or whatever), and you can stack these on top of each other. It shouldn't really matter whether you're decorating a `HtmlEmail` or a `SimpleEmail`.